# A good JavaScript form builder

Tags: javascript, forms, wysiwyg

The company I work for is building a product that revolves around client built forms. A client would come in, make his form in a user friendly UI (drag & drop all kinds of fields with conditional logic), and have others submit answers to it. Both the form and submitted answers should reside on my servers.

Can anyone recommend a form builder solution that can be used (mostly) out of the box? Doesn't matter if it's free or paid.

So far, I came up with form.io, MachForm, Orbeon and OhMyForm.